# Expected points of the loser in a ping-pong game

Tags: probability

If two ping-pong players play a game randomly, that is, each point is won by each player with equal probability (and independently of the other points), what is the expected number of points of the looser?  What if the probability of player "A" winning each point is a fixed number $p$?

Recall that a ping-pong game is played to 11 points, but let us assume for simplicity that whoever gets to 11 points first is the winner, without the usual requirement of a two-point margin for victory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: the loser ends up with $k$ points ($0 \le k \le 10$) if either
player $A$ wins $k$ points of the first $10+k$ and player $B$ wins the $11+k$'th point (thus winning on that point), or player $B$ wins $k$ points of the first $10+k$ and player $A$ wins the $11+k$'th.  Use binomial distributions.

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I am sorry my question was closed.  I have no idea what was the reason and unfortunately whoever closed it gave no indication why.  Nevertheless your answer was quite useful and I believe I can solve my problem with it.